# Collectors.toMap with method reference compiles but not with identity function lambda

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` which I'm trying to convert to a LinkedHashMap. The below statement gives me an error but another form works what is the difference

Below give an error `Bad return type in lambda expression: U cannot be converted to Employee`

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> collect = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, x-> x, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Below work

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> collect = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, Employee::getId, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two arguments of the `Collectors.toMap` are a key mapper and a value mapper, respectively.

`keyMapper = Employee::getName` is equivalent to `keyMapper = x -> x.getName()` and means that the key of the resulting map will be the name attribute of the employee (String).

`valueMapper = x -> x` means that the value of the resulting map will be the employee itself. That would only be possible if the result was of type `LinkedHashMap<String, Employee>` instead of `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>`, and that's why it fails.

`valueMapper = Employee::getId` is equivalent to `valueMapper = x -> x.getId()` and means that the value of the resulting map will be the id attribute of the employee (Integer). This is compatible with the result type `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>`.

That said, both the below are correct depending on the intended outcome:

```java
// map from name to Employee
LinkedHashMap<String, Employee> collect = employees.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getName(), x -> x, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

// map from name to Employee Id
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> collect = employees.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, Employee::getId, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> collect = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, x-> x, (oldValue, newValue) -> old, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

should be

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> collect = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, x-> x.getId(), (oldValue, newValue) -> old, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

note the `x-> x.getId()` difference insead of `x-> x`

Comment: yes but I want to understand the reason.

Comment: This is obviously because the Type of the value in the map is Integer and x is of Type Employee, so you need to call x.getId() to get the Integer ID.

Answer (score 0):

taking a look to the function definition of `Collection.toMap` from ***docs.oracle***:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-

`toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, Supplier<M> mapSupplier)`.

Since you want to create a `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>` than the `valueMapper` should provide an object of type `Integer` which is not the case in the first example `x->x` which is a lambda taking an `Employee` object and returns an `Employee` as well, whereas `Employee::getId` works fine since it returns an object of the correct type which is `Integer`  .